# how to fix print screen button not to take multiple shots in the same time?

Tags: keyboard, print-screen

Well I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, but I guess it applies to other versions too, the problem is that my `print screen` button is just on top of the `Backspace` button, and sometimes when I want to clear a word, I hit `print screen` by mistake which is simply because I work with many keyboards and not all of them have keys in a similar place.

The problem is that by pressing and holding `print screen` button just for a couple of seconds, Ubuntu starts taking tens of pictures **continuously** and filling the RAM, which I believe **leads to halt in the system** and wastes some time to recover from it.

1. I need `print screen`, don't want to disable it
2. Don't want to change it to another key so that I have to explain about why print screen is not working
3. Can we just make it take a single picture instead of thousands?
4. Can we disable the functionality partially and instead just use the combo version `Ctrl + PrtScr`?

P.S: It happened once when I was writing this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your best option is to use your point no. 4 and alter the keys used to take a screenshot. Perhaps not to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> as you have suggested, as in a default installation this is already being used to copy screenshots to the clipboard.

Navigate as follows:

```
Dash --> System Settings --> Hardware --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts --> Screenshots
```

Then click on 'Take a Screenshot' and where it says: 'New Accelerator' type in your new key combination. In the screenshot here you can see that I have used the 'Windows (Super)' key as well as The 'Print Screen' key:

[image]

And I suspect that this would be a good choice in your case as well and would fit neatly into your work flow...

Comment: it's a fair solution and I like it, tanx. But I really wish we could disable continuous capturing behavior !